# Export plot data from R to Excel

Tags: r

I have this plot which i generate it from this code:

```
m <- bcea(e=effects,c=costs, ref=2, interventions=treatments, Kmax=50000)
```

The plot is:

```
evi.plot(m)
```

Now, i need to export this evpi.plot(m) in an excel file, not the jpeg created, but the data along with it, i mean what created the X and Y axis.

I've been using something like this but it's not for this case

```
write.table( thresholds, 'clipboard', sep='\t', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE )
```

Comment: Try `str(m)`, to see structure of `m`, then choose variables used for plotting, and output them with `write.table`.

Comment: I think it is better to use `write.csv` or `write.csv2` to export to Excel. with `write.csv(m, "Data.plot.csv", row.names=FLASE, col.names=FALSE)` I think it will do it or you can subset here which variables do you want to print

Comment: from which package do `bcea` and `evi.plot` come from?

Comment: it comes from bcea package, it's used in cost effectivness... Thanks very much zx8754, i understood how to do it, please post this as a answer so i could accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation for function `bcea` from package `BCEA` you can see the structure of your object:

> Value
>
> An object of the class "bcea" containing the following elements
>
> n.sim  Number of simulations produced by the Bayesian model
>
> n.comparators  Number of interventions being analysed
>
> ...
>
> k 
>   The vector of values for the grid approximation of the willingness to pay
>
> ...
>
> evi    The vector of values for the Expected Value of Information, as a
>   function of the willingness to pay

And if you look at the function definition of `evi.plot` you will see that your x and y-values are the elements named `k` and `evi`:

```
> evi.plot
function (he) 
{
    options(scipen = 10)
    plot(he$k, he$evi, t = "l", xlab = "Willingness to pay", 
        ylab = "EVPI", main = "Expected Value of Information")
    if (length(he$kstar) > 0) {
        points(rep(he$kstar, 3), c(-10000, he$evi[he$k == he$kstar]/2, 
            he$evi[he$k == he$kstar]), t = "l", lty = 2, col = "dark grey")
        points(c(-10000, he$kstar/2, he$kstar), rep(he$evi[he$k == 
            he$kstar], 3), t = "l", lty = 2, col = "dark grey")
    }
}
<environment: namespace:BCEA>
```

So:

```
res <- cbind(m$k, m$evi)
write.table(res, file="bcea.csv", sep=',', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE )
```